# Database connection take time when user log-off?  or signout from asp.net problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ms-access

i have ASP.NET application,

when user log-off, and immediately trying to log-in again,it fails and page is waiting, after 20 seconds the page logins, i think the connection with database, e.g Access, inst closed.
what i need to do when user log-off to close all the database conenction instances. 
i am using this code when the user click log-off button:

```
protected void closeCon()
{
    //to close access
    OleDbConnection sqlconConnection = (OleDbConnection)DatabaseConnection.Instance.GetConnection();

    sqlconConnection.Close();
    // to close sql server
    SqlConnection sqlconConnection1 = (SqlConnection)(SqlConnection)DatabaseConnection.Instance.GetConnection();

    if (sqlconConnection1.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        sqlconConnection1.Close();        
    }
}
     Session.Abandon();
    HttpCookie ObjCookie = new HttpCookie("ourcase");
    ObjCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ObjCookie);
    Response.Redirect("/login/default.aspx");
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: Your site will fail horribly when you receive multiple requests at once.  You should completely redesign your database connectivity; **do not share connection instances**.

Comment: @ abatishchev, i close all the connections i opend, but still , is there any way to close any open connections?

Comment: lol - @abatishchev, maybe instead of rushing to be the first to edit, take a moment and check for all your typos first?

Comment: @Tony Toews i have problem with log-in,when a user signout, and then immediately try to sign-in,it fails, he wait for like 10 sec or 20 secs. `Session.Abandon();
        HttpCookie ObjCookie = new HttpCookie("ourcase");
        ObjCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ObjCookie);
        Response.Redirect("/login/default.aspx");
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        ;` i am using all the possible thing to cleare the chace to remove cooking and rediret to login but when it come to login again it fails.

Comment: I see my name mentioned here but I don't see my original comment so I have no idea what I typed.

Comment: @Tony Toews Yes you are right, you have addressed and issue like this in another question, So i post a comment to you to look at the current question and give me an idea to deal with it :)

Comment: Ahh, ok.  However I have no idea as to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`dbConn.Close()` should close the database connection.

Alternatively, where you are using the database connections, you could use a `using` statement that will automatically close and dispose of the connection object after it is finished with.  This is psuedo code:

```
using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection())
{
    // do your db work here
}
```

Comment: @ardman, is there any way to force the d.b to be close when user log-off?

Comment: @safi: you can add the call to the `Close` method in your `LogOff` method, assuming you have a `LogOff` method.  But, in all honesty, you shouldn't be keeping a database connection open for this period of time.

Comment: @ardman, so which is the best way? to end all session when user log off?

Comment: @safi:  Use the `using` method so it handles the database closure automatically.

Comment: @safi: The connection / query should only be open long enough to get the data.  After that it should be immediately closed.  No connections should be left around to be cleaned up by a log off method.

Comment: @Neil Knight i have problem with log-in,when a user signout, and then immediately try to sign-in,it fails, he wait for like 10 sec or 20 secs.`Session.Abandon(); HttpCookie ObjCookie = new HttpCookie("ourcase"); ObjCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now; HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ObjCookie); Response.Redirect("/login/default.aspx"); System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` ; i am using all the possible thing to cleare the cache to remove cooking and rediret to login but when it come to login again it fails

Comment: You will probably find that this is to stop hacks to your site.  I will try and find out some more information for you.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what [@Ardman said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886806/database-connection-take-time-when-user-log-off/4886818#4886818), always wrap the connection in a `using` statement.

```
using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection())
{
    // do your db work here
}
```

But since Access [supports connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810829.aspx), you should open and close the connection on each trip to the database.

Not each time a user logs on and off.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The problem with Jet/ACE is that creating the LDB (locking) file (or writing to one that's already in use by other users) is a very expensive process, so with Jet/ACE, you generally use a persistent connection rather than opening and closing it repeatedly. I'm not sure how connection pooling interacts with that, though. I'm wary of the idea that each user would have their own connection, as opposed to there being a top-level connection for all users to use. Remember, it's only Jet/ACE, not a server database...

Comment: i have problem with log-in,when a user signout, and then immediately try to sign-in,it fails, he wait for like 10 sec or 20 secs.`Session.Abandon(); HttpCookie ObjCookie = new HttpCookie("ourcase"); ObjCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now; HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ObjCookie); Response.Redirect("/login/default.aspx"); System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` ; i am using all the possible thing to cleare the cache to remove cooking and rediret to login but when it come to login again it fails.